# Add values together based on title

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got different products and bundles, but want to see how many individual items I am selling each day.

I've got 2 specific products that are in 5 different forms:

- Product A: Single
- Product B: Single
- Product A & B: Bundle
- Product A: 2 Pack
- Product B: 2 Pack

I've got a query written that gets each SKU and the number of units, but I want to get the total number sold of each individual item. What I have currently is as follows:

```
select product_title, purchase_date,
case
when product_title like "%2-Pack" then units_sold*3
else units_sold 
end as units
from (
select product_title, purchase_date, count(*) as units_sold
from (
select timestamp_trunc(processed_at, DAY, "UTC") as purchase_date, product_title

from (

SELECT * EXCEPT(instance, line_items, id, fulfillment_status, name, tax_lines) FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `shopify.orders`) o cross join UNNEST(line_items) as item
  join `shopify.sku` sk on sk.product_sku = sku

WHERE instance = 1
ORDER BY processed_at desc

)

WHERE email <> ""
ORDER BY email DESC
)
where date(purchase_date) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) and date(purchase_date) = 
current_date() and product_title like "%Product%"
group by product_title, purchase_date
order by purchase_date desc
)
```

Let's say on a single day, I sell 10 singles of product A and 20 singles of product B. I also sell 10 bundles, 5 2 packs of product A, and 10 2 packs of product B. I want the following:

- Product A: 30 (10+10+5*2)
- Product B: 50 (20+10+10*2)

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I'm having the hardest time getting the bundle into each bucket.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query seems ludicrously complex to do what the question is asking, so it clearly has logic to do additional things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following approach

Dummy Data:

```
WITH 
data as
(
SELECT CAST('2020-08-20' AS DATE) AS purchase_date,10 As qty, 'Product A: Single' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-20' AS DATE),20 As qty, 'Product B: Single' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-20' AS DATE),5 As qty, 'Product A & B:Bundle' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-20' AS DATE),10 As qty, 'Product A: 2 Pack' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-20' AS DATE),20 As qty, 'Product B: 2 Pack' As Product

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST('2020-08-19' AS DATE) AS purchase_date,20 As qty, 'Product A: Single' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-19' AS DATE),10 As qty, 'Product B: Single' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-19' AS DATE),10 As qty, 'Product A & B:Bundle' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-19' AS DATE),15 As qty, 'Product A: 2 Pack' As Product
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('2020-08-19' AS DATE),25 As qty, 'Product B: 2 Pack' As Product

),
```

I am splitting each category and calculating individual sales by product type:

```
sales_split
AS
(
Select purchase_date, CASE WHEN Product like '%A: 2 Pack' THEN qty*2 ELSE 0 END A_2_pack_split,
CASE WHEN Product like '%B: 2 Pack' THEN qty*2 ELSE 0 END B_2_pack_split,
CASE WHEN Product like '%Bundle' THEN qty ELSE 0 END A_Bundle,
CASE WHEN Product like '%Bundle' THEN qty ELSE 0 END B_Bundle,
CASE WHEN Product like '%A: Single' THEN qty ELSE 0 END A_Single,
CASE WHEN Product like '%B: Single' THEN qty ELSE 0 END B_Single
FROM data
),
```

Aggregating all sales at product A and B level:

```
calculations
AS
(
SELECT purchase_date,(A_2_pack_split + A_Bundle + A_Single) A_total_sales,(B_2_pack_split + B_Bundle + B_Single) B_total_sales
FROM sales_split
)
```

Now Aggregating at purchase date level:

```
SELECT c.purchase_date,SUM(A_total_sales) A_sales,SUM(B_total_sales) B_sales
FROM calculations c
GROUP BY purchase_date
```